# Creating RPN calculator using c#.NET with expression trees

Tags: c#, algorithm, .net-core, tree

I am new to expression trees and haven't done c# in a  while now. 
I need to create reverse polish notation calculator using expression trees.

So far I have created 2 stacks one is for operations and the other is for numbers.
I am wondering how to split the user input and call it in the following expression

```
Expression<Func<double, double, double, double>> calc = (x, y, z) => x + y - z;
 //sample input 11 6 5 4 + - / 7 * 2 2 2 + - 

    //my expression class
 class Expression : ExpressionVisitor
{
    Stack<int> nums = new Stack<int>();
    Stack<char> ops = new Stack<char>();



    public override Expression Visit(Expression node)
    {
        if (node == null)
        {
            return null;
        }
        switch (node.NodeType)
        {

            case ExpressionType.Add:
                return this.VisitBinary((BinaryExpression)node); 
            case ExpressionType.Subtract:
                return this.VisitBinary((BinaryExpression)node);
            case ExpressionType.Multiply:
                return this.VisitBinary((BinaryExpression)node);
            case ExpressionType.Divide:
                return this.VisitBinary((BinaryExpression)node);
            case ExpressionType.Power:
                return this.VisitBinary((BinaryExpression)node);
            default:
                return base.Visit(node);

        }
    }


    protected override Expression VisitBinary(BinaryExpression node)
    {

        var rightSide = this.Visit(node.rightSide);


        var leftSide = this.Visit(node.leftSide);
        switch (node.NodeType)
        {
            case ExpressionType.Add:
                return Expression.MakeBinary(ExpressionType.Add, leftSide, rightSide);
            case ExpressionType.Subtract:
                return Expression.MakeBinary(ExpressionType.Subtract, leftSide, rightSide);
            case ExpressionType.Multiply:
              return  Expression.MakeBinary(ExpressionType.Multiply, leftSide, rightSide);
            case ExpressionType.Divide:
              return  Expression.MakeBinary(ExpressionType.Divide, leftSide, rightSide);
            case ExpressionType.Power:
                return Expression.MakeBinary(ExpressionType.Power, leftSide, rightSide);

            default:
                return base.VisitBinary(node);
        }

//main class    
static void Main(string[] args)
    {


        var visitor = new Expression();
        string input = Console.ReadLine();
        string[] rpnTokens = input.Split(' ');
        Expression<Func<double, double, double, double>> calc = (x, y, z) => x + y - z;

        Console.WriteLine("result: " + calc);


    }
```

Comment: Your first line of code already does that; it creates an expression tree from the numeric expression you provided.  If you're asking how to get that expression from a string that the user provides, you need a parser; there's plenty of advice on the Internet on how to do that.  Here's [one such article](http://www.aboutmycode.com/net-framework/building-expression-evaluator-with-expression-trees-in-csharp-part-1/).

Answer (score 0):

With Reverse Polish Notation, the user input is acted on in the order that it's entered.

- **Split the user input** into a sequence of operands and operators (call them tokens).
- Create one empty stack to hold operands and intermediate results.
- Act on the user input (that is, **'call it'**) in sequence order (for your sample input, the sequence would be 11, then 6, then 5, etc.)

  - For an operand, push the operand onto the stack.
  - For an operator

    - Pop operand 2 off the stack
    - Pop operand 1 off the stack
    - Push the result of the operator applied to operand 1 and operand 2 onto the stack
- After the last token is acted on, there should be one value left on the stack; the result of the expression.

Is this using an expression tree to create an RPN calculator?
The input string is equivalent to an expression tree (see [example expression tree](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/expression-tree/)).  It encodes the same information; namely, a sequence of operations.  The '5' and the '4' must be added before the result can be subtracted from '6', etc.  So, maybe a better way to say it is that the equivalent of an expression tree is used as input to an RPN calculator.

---

Example using the sample input from the code snippet.

```
Empty stack              {}
Push 11                  {11}
Push 6                   {11, 6}
Push 5                   {11, 6, 5}
Push 4                   {11, 6, 5, 4}

Pop operand 2, = 4       {11, 6, 5}
Pop operand 1, = 5       {11, 6}
Push + operator result   {11, 6, 9}

Pop operand 2 = 9        {11, 6}
Pop operand 1 = 6        {11}
Push - operator result   {11, -3}

Pop operand 2 = -3       {11}
Pop operand 1 = 11       {}
Push / operator result   {-11/3}

Push 7                   {-11/3, 7}

Pop operand 2 = 7        {-11/3}
Pop operand 1 = -11/3    {}
Push * operator result   {-77/3}

Push 2                   {-77/3, 2}
Push 2                   {-77/3, 2, 2}
Push 2                   {-77/3, 2, 2, 2}

Pop operand 2 = 2        {-77/3, 2, 2}
Pop operand 1 = 2        {-77/3, 2}
Push + operator result   {-77/3, 2, 4}

Pop operand 2 = 4        {-77/3, 2}
Pop operand 1 = 2        {-77/3}
Push - operator result   {-77/3, -2}

NOTE:  There are two values left on the stack, so the expression is incomplete.
Let's add a '+' operator to complete it.

Pop operand 2 = -2       {-77/3}
Pop operand 1 = -77/3    {}
Push + operator result   {-83/3}

So, there are no more tokens *and* there is one value on the stack.  Success!

Pop final result = -83/3 {}
```